# bootstrap datalist issue in Google Chrome

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap datalist to display items.
In FF, the items are automatically showing once start typing. but it is not showing in Google Chrome. what could be the issue with Chrome?

```
<datalist id="d1">
  <option>13:59</option>
  <option>3:55</option>
  <option>6:55</option>
</datalist>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a datalist is used to give the user some options to choose from. For example by an input field you can add a datalist with some default options to give the user some suggestions.

if you just want an option select use `<select>`
but if you want it to work like you asked (in chrome 20+), see my fiddle or example code below.

be sure to choose a matching ID in this case 'd1'

```
<input list="d1">
<datalist id="d1">
  <option>13:59</option>
  <option>3:55</option>
  <option>6:55</option>
</datalist>
```

Click to see it work on fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5c0ksoa0/2/)

> w3schools says that it is not supported in **Safari**

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too in latest Chrome versions.
It happens when a value exists in the input field.
I think it tries to filter the list by value in input field so it display nothing when the drop-down button is clicked.